# не могу ввести сколько правильных ответа помогите

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [
    {
        question: "3+3",
        answer: [6, 5, 4, 3],
        exect: 6
    },
    {
        question: "4+8",
        answer: [11, 12, 14, 9],
        exect: 12
    },
    {
        question: "7+9",
        answer: [16, 14, 17, 10],
        exect: "0"
    },
    {
        question: "88-44",
        answer: [44, 24, 88, 0],
        exect: 44
    },
    {
        question: "81/9",
        answer: [9, 7, 5, 4],
        exect: 9
    },
    {
        question: "15+16",
        answer: [15, 28, 31, 77],
        exect: 31
    },
    {
        question: "88-24",
        answer: [66, 60, 54, 64],
        exect: 64
    },
    {
        question: "55+5",
        answer: [60, 35, 24, 11],
        exect: 60
    },
    {
        question: "11-1",
        answer: [12, 14, 10, 1],
        exect: 10
    },
    {
        question: "12+2+4",
        answer: [18, 15, 11, 13],
        exect: 18
    }

];


function ss() {
    var radios_length = document.getElementsByClassName('ans');
    var value;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios_length.length; i++) {
        if (radios_length[i].checked) {
            value = radios_length[i].value;
            alert(value);
return value;
        }

    }

}


function myfunction() {
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById("mouse");
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    // alert(answ.getAttribute('value'))


    // alert(data[x].answer.length);
    document.write("<h1>" + data[x].question + "</h1>");
    for (var j = 0; j < data[x].answer.length; j++) {
        document.write("<h3>" + "<input onclick='ss()'   class='ans' type='radio' name='answer' value='" + data[x].answer[j] + "' checked='checked' >" + data[x].answer[j] + "</h3>")
        var chisht = data[x].exect;

        continue;


    }
    if (ss().value == data[x].exect){
        console.log("ok")
    }

}
```

Comment: не могу ввести сколько правильных ответа помогите

Comment: Не ясно, что требуется. Опишите проблему подробнее, добавив описание в сам вопрос. И проведите, пожалуйста, форматирование своего кода

Comment: нада игру как опросы и я не могу узнать правильно ответил или нет

Answer (score 1):

Немного изменил код. После клика на зелёном квадрате выводится вопрос. При выборе ответа, если ответ правильный выводится `ok`, или `error`, если неправильно.

```js
var data = [
{
 question: "3+3",
 answer: [6, 5, 4, 3],
 exect: 6
},
{
 question: "4+8",
 answer: [11, 12, 14, 9],
 exect: 12
},
{
 question: "7+9",
 answer: [16, 14, 17, 10],
 exect: "0"
},
{
 question: "88-44",
 answer: [44, 24, 88, 0],
 exect: 44
},
{
 question: "81/9",
 answer: [9, 7, 5, 4],
 exect: 9
},
{
 question: "15+16",
 answer: [15, 28, 31, 77],
 exect: 31
},
{
 question: "88-24",
 answer: [66, 60, 54, 64],
 exect: 64
},
{
 question: "55+5",
 answer: [60, 35, 24, 11],
 exect: 60
},
{
 question: "11-1",
 answer: [12, 14, 10, 1],
 exect: 10
},
{
 question: "12+2+4",
 answer: [18, 15, 11, 13],
 exect: 18
}

];

function ss(x, otvet)
{
 if(data[x].exect == otvet)
 {
  alert("ok");
 }
 else
 {
  alert("error");
 }
}

function myfunction()
{
 document.getElementById("mouse");
 var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

 var a = document.getElementById("vopros");
 a.innerHTML = "<h1>" + data[x].question + "</h1>";
 for(var j = 0; j < data[x].answer.length; j++)
 {
  a.innerHTML += '<h3><input onclick="ss(' + x + ', ' + data[x].answer[j] + ')" type="radio" >' + data[x].answer[j] + '</h3>';
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="vopros"></div>
<div id="mouse" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: green" onclick="myfunction()"></div>
```